# Overlay the function signature in goSublime

Tags: go, sublimetext3, gosublime

I am using GoSublime with Sublime Text 3.

Often times in a large project I'd like to see the (function) caller's return arg types and while GoSublime enables me to "Go to" the declaration, that's still sub-optimal, compared to having an overlay that could just show up at the callee

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

After two and half years working with go and trying different IDEs, we have moved from Sublime Text to Visual Studio Code.

We had been using Visual Studio Code with the Go plugin for the last 6 months and it's the best Go experience you can have. If you integrate Delve debugger with it you get a really good coding framework.

So my recommendation is that you move to VSC and give away Sublime Text.

This is how it looks what you are looking in Visual Studio Code:

[image]

Comment: thats interesting. I havent heard of VSC so I'll definitely take a run with it. Im curious, what would you say is the learning curve of VSC compared to ST3? I spent some time learning to be efficient on ST3. Would you say VSC has an easier, equal or harder learning curve?

Comment: I would say they are very similar to learn, VSC it's very similar to Atom but Microsoft did a really good job with it. I used ST3 a lot before VSC and for GO projects the difference it's quite big.
And the most important feature is the integration with Delve debugger, it's fully integrated in the editor.